# Slow redirects on android with expo-router

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, router, expo-router

I use expo-router and there is a very big delay on android when navigating between pages (on ios there is very little delay, on web everything happens instantly)

I also tried to insert console.log in the components I go to, but it is executed instantly, and then you have to wait a few seconds for the page to display, also removed images from pages but it did not help.

Upd:
I changed `<Slot/>` to `<Stack/>` and it works good on all devices, why can slot influence on slowing down the redirects?

package.json

```
{
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --go",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "update": "eas update --branch preview --message \"Updating the app\"",
    "build": "eas build -p android --profile preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "effector": "^23.2.0",
    "effector-react": "^23.2.0",
    "expo": "~50.0.6",
    "expo-dev-client": "~3.3.8",
    "expo-device": "~5.9.3",
    "expo-font": "~11.10.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.2.2",
    "expo-router": "~3.4.7",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.9.3",
    "expo-task-manager": "~11.7.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.24.10",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.8.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-svg": "14.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-universe": "^12.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.3.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "zlno-rn",
    "slug": "zlno-rn",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./src/assets/images/icon.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./src/assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.feip.zlno"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./src/assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.feip.zlno"
    },
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro",
      "output": "static",
      "favicon": "./src/assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      [
        "expo-updates",
        {
          "username": "grnv"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "extra": {
      "router": {
        "origin": false
      },
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "179559a6-40d3-4039-9684-a5b67cfe25f9"
      }
    },
    "runtimeVersion": "1.0.0",
    "updates": {
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/179559a6-40d3-4039-9684-a5b67cfe25f9",
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 60000
    },
    "owner": "grnv2"
  }
}
```

[router structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QoV8.png)

index.tsx

```
import { useRootNavigationState, Redirect } from 'expo-router';

export default function App() {
    const rootNavigationState = useRootNavigationState();

    if (!rootNavigationState?.key) return null;

    return <Redirect href="/home" />;
}
```

_layout.tsx

```
import FontAwesome from '@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import Home from '@screens/Home';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { Slot } from 'expo-router';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export {
    // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
    ErrorBoundary,
} from 'expo-router';

export const unstable_settings = {
    // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
    initialRouteName: '(tabs)',
};

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
    const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
        SpaceMono: require('@assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
        RobotoBlack: require('@assets/fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf'),
        RobotoBlackItalic: require('@assets/fonts/Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf'),
        RobotoBold: require('@assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf'),
        RobotoBoldItalic: require('@assets/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf'),
        RobotoItalic: require('@assets/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf'),
        RobotoLight: require('@assets/fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf'),
        RobotoLightItalic: require('@assets/fonts/Roboto-LightItalic.ttf'),
        RobotoMedium: require('@assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf'),
        RobotoMediumItalic: require('@assets/fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'),
        RobotoRegular: require('@assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf'),
        RobotoThin: require('@assets/fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf'),
        RobotoThinItalic: require('@assets/fonts/Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf'),
        MontserratRegular: require('@assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
        MontserratLight: require('@assets/fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf'),
        ...FontAwesome.font,
    });

    // Expo Router uses Error Boundaries to catch errors in the navigation tree.
    useEffect(() => {
        if (error) throw error;
    }, [error]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (loaded) {
            SplashScreen.hideAsync();
        }
    }, [loaded]);

    if (!loaded) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Slot />
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are navigating to the next screen that is too heavy and has more thing to render on the initial render. you can optimize the screen by [lazy loading](https://medium.com/@Blochware/code-splitting-and-lazy-loading-in-react-native-boosting-app-performance-2bc0592fe231).

load only those components that necessary and lazy load the other.  you can also use a hook useIsReady

import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import React from 'react';

```
const useIsReady = (stack = true) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeFocus = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      if (!isReady) setIsReady(true);
    });

    const unsubscribeTransitionEnd = stack
      ? // @ts-ignore
        navigation.addListener('transitionEnd', () => {
          if (!isReady) setIsReady(true);
        })
      : undefined;

    return () => {
      unsubscribeFocus();
      unsubscribeTransitionEnd && unsubscribeTransitionEnd();
    };
  }, []);
  return isReady;
};

export default useIsReady;
```

you can use this like this

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import useIsReady from "./useIsReady";

function MyComponent({ children }) {
  const isReady = useIsReady();

  return (
    <View>
      {!isReady ? (
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      ) : (
        children
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```